# How do I store output in a variable from Windows "where" command, in a batch file?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, command-line, path

I am using the "where" command from a Windows batch file to find the location of my java installation for a script

so normally from a commandline,

```
C:\Users\user>where java
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

Now I need to be able to get the output path of "where" in a variable for later use in my batch file, how do I do that?

I tried something like,

```
@echo off
cls
set var=1
setlocal enableextensions
for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in ('where java') do (
    set var=%%F
)
echo %var%
endlocal
pause
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to remove usebackq option in this case , or to use backquotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('where java') do set var=%%F 
ECHO %var%
```

For me, this outputs:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe